# Instantiate a sprite using json data value (C# Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gambling

Here is my code :

**BetBoard_Test.cs**

```
 //Scoreboard
[SerializeField] protected GameObject prefab_big_road = null;

[SerializeField] Transform pos_big_road = null;

string jsonString = "[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]"; //sample data

private void Start()
{

    ExampleClass dataParser = new ExampleClass();
    dataParser.dataToParse = jsonString;

    //Convert to Json
    string exampleClassToJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(dataParser);
    Debug.Log(exampleClassToJson);

    ExampleClass obj = JsonUtility.FromJson<ExampleClass>(exampleClassToJson);
    //Loop over it
    for (int i = 1; i < obj.dataToParse.Length - 1; i += 3)
    {
        char indivisualChar = obj.dataToParse[i];

        Debug.Log(indivisualChar);
    }

    WinLog();
}

IEnumerator WinLog_big_road()
{
    DeleteChildrens(pos_big_road);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    int[] array_big_road = tzPlayInfo.Instance._BIG_ROAD_;

    for (int i = 0; i < rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_ * rh.Const._HISTORY_HEIGHT_; i++)
    {
        if (array_big_road[i] == 0) continue;

        int x = i % rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_;
        int y = i / rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_;
        float xl = 9.0f;
        float yl = -8.0f;

        GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one; //(1,1,1)

        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * xl, y * yl, 0f);
        o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = array_big_road[i] == 1 ? "layout_player_bigline-01" : "layout_banker_bigline-01";

        NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
    yield break;
}

    void DeleteChildrens(Transform t)
    {
        NGUITools.DestroyChildren(t);
    }

    public void WinLog()
    {
        StopCoroutine("WinLog_big_road");
        StartCoroutine("WinLog_big_road");
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string dataToParse;
}
```

**ConstantValue.cs**

```
public const int _HISTORY_COUNT_ = 70;
public const int _HISTORY_HEIGHT_ = 6;
```

**PlayInfo.cs**

```
public int[] _BIG_ROAD_ = new int[Const._HISTORY_COUNT_ * Const._HISTORY_HEIGHT_ ];
```

What i am trying to achieve here is that *see image*

[image]

my `jsonString="[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]";` that is converted into json format needs to do it something like this for example

```
1 = blue circle
2 = red circle
```

[image]

just like that in the picture every value on my json data needs to be instantiated with the sprite that is equivalent to 1 and 2 which is i have this condition `o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = array_big_road[i] == 1 ? "layout_player_bigline-01" : "layout_banker_bigline-01";`

PS: I am very sorry if i couldn't explain it very well because english is not my native so i provided a picture. I am very sorry.

EDIT: I did it like this but the problem is that it's not getting what i want all the red which is `2` is the only appearing on the board

```
 for (int i = 1; i < obj.dataToParse.Length - 1; i += 3)
    {
        char indivisualChar = obj.dataToParse[i];
        int j = 0;

        if(j < rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_ * rh.Const._HISTORY_HEIGHT_)
        {
            //lets increment it
            j++;
            //instantiate the sprite
            GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road) as GameObject;
            o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road);
            o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one; //(1,1,1)
            int x = j % rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_;
            int y = j / rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_;
            float xl = 9.0f;
            float yl = -8.0f;
            o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * xl, y * yl, 0f);
            //o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = indivisualChar == 1 ? "layout_player_bigline-01" : "layout_banker_bigline-01";
            if (indivisualChar == 1)
            {
                o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
                NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
            }
            else
            {
                o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
                NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
            }
        }
       //Debug.Log(indivisualChar);
    }
```

EDITED: More information.

It just give me this

[image]

All of the sprites are in one place and the second problem of that is all the prefab that is cloned is always **red** (`2`)

[image]

Comment: As far as I have understood, you only set the sprite name on the above code, but didn't set a sprite actually. You need to set the sprite from a prefab may be

Comment: In that `for` loop, if `indivisualChar` is `1` instantiate blue. If it is `2` instantiate red. Not sure where you are lost but this is all you need to do.

Comment: @Programmer I edit my question sir and added some information . I try to code this but its not getting what i want

Comment: @ZayedUpal Sorry i updated my question because i tried something

Comment: Sorry I don't use NGUI. I use Unity's UI system but your edit is looking good. If you are not getting what you expected I think you should post a screenshot of what you are getting now maybe someone that uses NGUI will help you out

Comment: @Programmer i guess its not about the NGUI. Could you help me please

Comment: IT mattes which UI system you are using. If you are using Unity UI, you can do this with the *Grid Layout Group* component. You may want to start using Unity UI or ask the question about NGUI on their site

Comment: @Programmer hi can u please help me. Here is a more concrete question . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913711/get-json-data-and-parse-the-data-individually-c-unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue about all game prefab that are instantiated is all red so what at i did here was like this.

```
char indivisualChar = obj.dataToParse[i];
int j = 0;

if (j < rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_ * rh.Const._HISTORY_HEIGHT_)
{
  //lets increment it
  j++;
  //instantiate the sprite
  GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road) as GameObject;
  o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road);
  o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one; //(1,1,1)
  int x = j % rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_;
  int y = j / rh.Const._HISTORY_COUNT_;
  float xl = 2.0f;
  float yl = -22.0f;
  o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x * xl, y * yl, 0f);
  o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = indivisualChar == '1' ? "layout_player_bigline-01" : "layout_banker_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }
```

Thanks.